# is there a way to extract string in XCode ios project for i18n

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, internationalization

is there a way to extract string in XCode ios project for i18n, I need to auto find strings and make localized files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is only possible to auto find NSLocalizedString...(...); methods and extract the keys from them. If you haven't already used on of these macros during development, you can't extract every NSString in the Project. I am pretty sure this would always lead to broken code as you can't simply replace every NSString with an NSLocalizedString statement.

To look for NSLocalizedString stuff in your code, genstrings is the way you want to go: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/genstrings.1.html

Answer (score 0):

with a few months late (sorry): genstrings and ibtool will extract from .m or .xib your strings.

edit: oups, my bad, genstrings will only extract strings being called inside a NSLocalizedString function. Maybe that could fit your need with a search-and-replace before genstrings.